# Filtering by a column by string values from a different column

Tags: r, string, filter, columnsorting

Let me introduce a similar problem to that I encountered

```
a <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
b <- c("Saturday", "Sunday")
```

I want to filter/remove values of b from a, meaning I only need to end up with 5 days.
To complicate the matter, I have a df_1 with 3000 columns of data(strings) and another df_2 with 700 columns to filter accordingly. I need to end up with 3000 - 700 = 2300 values at best, but some from df_2 might not be in df_1! Please help my boiling brain. Thanks

I tried using:

```
str_detect
df_1 %>% filter(print(across(everything(), ~ !str_detect(.,df_2))))
```

no luck so far, the issue must be the method I am using

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? Difficult to help you without something to test the code on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(a, b)
# [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"
```

Or by indexing

```
a[!(a %in% b)]
# [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"
```